# NiFi Executestreamcommand Calling Shell

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a requirement to move the files to archive folder once rest of the processors completed so add executestreamcommand as a last component and calling a shell script to move the file to archive folder.

Though script runs from backend it's failing with  "permissions denied " error. Any idea what could be the issue here?

Also is there a way I know what user it is using to run the script.

Appreciate your support on it.

Thanks,

Kumar

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? Was it just a permission issue or something else with the use of this processor? I have same kind of issue. It does not appear to be a user permission problem. Just rying to run the 'mv target destination' command

Answer (score 0):

The user running the command from ExecuteStreamCommand is the same user that the NiFi process is running as e.g. `nifi`. So that user needs the appropriate permissions on the source and target directories.

If you don't know what the user is called, you can either check which user the process is running as with `ps` or you could look at who owns the NiFi home directories.

Comment: Thanks alot. Will check it.

Comment: looks like it's running as nifi user. is there any way I can get the script run as different user through Executestreamcommand processor

Comment: If NiFi can impersonate the user, then you could use that as you would in any bash script. But it would be easier to just put the NiFi user in a group that has permissions on the directories instead.

Answer (score 0):

Log onto the box where nifi is runing with the user that is running the nifi service, validate your script and then run it thru nifi interface.